# no return found in function error when there is a return

Tags: mysql

I've created a simple function in **MySQL** which is intended to calculate a posts score for later use in another procedure. However, I have come across the error:

> **MySQL** said: *#1320 - No RETURN found in FUNCTION database.getTrackScore*

**MySQL** isn't exactly my most proficient language, but as far as I can tell (at least while referencing the official documentation) all my syntax *seems* to be correct and I do indeed have a return at the end of my function.

This is my code:

```
SET @adjustedPlays = plays / 10000;
SET @adjustedSaves = saves * GREATEST(LEAST(2 * @adjustedPlays, 2), 1);
SET @adjustedReposts = reposts * GREATEST(LEAST(18 * @adjustedPlays, 18), 1);
SET @adjustedComments = comments * GREATEST(LEAST(65 * @adjustedPlays, 65), 1);

RETURN LOG10(ABS(plays + @adjustedSaves + @adjustedReposts + @adjustedComments));
```

All help is appreciated.

Comment: WHere is the `BEGIN` and `END`

Comment: @RiggsFolly I'm assuming it's automatically added in. While I'm learning I'm just using PHPMyAdmin's built-in procedure/function creator.

Comment: @RiggsFolly I've changed the code to just what I can see. I thought it might be of use to include what PHPMyAdmin returned in the console, but I can see it might give some confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing a BEGIN and END, and possibly the DELIMITERs as well, try

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE FUNCTION `getTrackScore`(`plays` INT UNSIGNED, `saves` INT UNSIGNED, `reposts` INT UNSIGNED, `comments` INT UNSIGNED) 
    RETURNS FLOAT  NOT DETERMINISTIC NO SQL SQL SECURITY DEFINER 
BEGIN
SET @adjustedPlays = plays / 10000;
SET @adjustedSaves = saves * GREATEST(LEAST(2 * @adjustedPlays, 2), 1);
SET @adjustedReposts = reposts * GREATEST(LEAST(18 * @adjustedPlays, 18), 1);
SET @adjustedComments = comments * GREATEST(LEAST(65 * @adjustedPlays, 65), 1);

RETURN (LOG10(ABS(plays + @adjustedSaves + @adjustedReposts + @adjustedComments)));
END; //
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: I have no idea how PHPMyAdmin messed it up, but thank you, this seemed to fix my problem :-)